# How to do load balancing / port forwarding on Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, load-balancing, portforwarding

I am evaluating the convenience of moving to azure. Currently, I am trying to figure out how to balance the load and make routing for different websites on the same machine. I saw tutorials where a user created a separate LB on a different VM. I also found many articles about the possibility to balance the load using *Azure load balancing*.

So I assume both are possible, is that correct?

I would like to know how to connect between machines on azure. Would it be possible to do so using a local ip, machinename, or dns?

I also need to figure out how to forward traffic to different ports based on http header, is that possible without a seperate machine as load balancer? I see the endpoint config in my azure dashboard and found the official documentation, but unfortunately it's not enough for my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently, I am trying to figure out how to balance the load and make
>   routing for different websites on the same machine.

You can have different web sites on the same machine by configuring virtual hosting on IIS. This is accomplished using host header. VM, Cloud Service or even Websites supports this functionality. VMs and Cloud Services should be pretty straight forward. Example using websites:

**Hosting multiple domains under one Azure Website**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cschotte/archive/2013/05/30/hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-azure.aspx

> I also found many articles about the possibility to balance the load
>   using Azure load balancing.

LB for VMs are as easy as creating a load balance set inside endpoint configuration wizard. Once you create a balance set, for example, enpoint HTTP port 80, you can assign this balance set to any VM on the same cloud service. All requests to port 80 would be automatically balanced across all VMs in the set.

> So I assume both are possible, is that correct?

Yes.

> I would like to know how to connect between machines on azure. Would
>   it be possible to do so using a local ip, machinename, or dns?

You just have to create a virtual network and deploy the VMs to it. Websites (through preview portal only), Cloud Services and VMs supports VNet.

**Virtual Network Overview**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj156007.aspx/

> I also need to figure out how to forward traffic to different ports
>   based on http header, is that possible without a seperate machine as
>   load balancer?

Not at this moment. Best you can have with native Azure Services is a 3-tuple (Source IP, Destination IP, Protocol) load balance configuration.

**Azure Load Balancer new distribution mode**

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/

Answer (score 1):

depending on how you're deploying there's a couple of options:

- first of all: LB sets in VM's in a cloud service. For this the Cloud service acts as the LB. this can only be achieved when using a standard sku VM.
- second of all in Azure WebApps : load balancing is achieved automagically when deploying through standard means, since scaling is foreseen here.
- Third of all there's Cloud Services with roles, who also do this "automagically".

Now none of that seem to apply to your needs. you can also start thinking about using traffic manager, something with a little more bite :-)

have you read this article by any chance? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/

I'd like to advise you to add different endpoints to your VM's work with traffic manager and ake sure you IIS has all the headers on the correct ports (cause i'm assuming that's what you're doing already)